# How to join on a nested value from a jsonb column?

Tags: sql, postgresql, left-join, jsonb, set-returning-functions

I have a PostgreSQL 11 database with these tables:

```
CREATE TABLE stats (
   id integer NOT NULL,
   uid integer NOT NULL,
   date date NOT NULL,
   data jsonb DEFAULT '[]'::json NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO stats(id, uid, date, data) VALUES
   (1, 1, '2020-10-01', '{"somerandomhash":{"source":"thesource"}}');

CREATE TABLE links(
   id integer NOT NULL,
   uuid uuid NOT NULL,
   path text NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO links(id, uuid, path) VALUES
   (1, 'acbd18db-4cc2-f85c-edef-654fccc4a4d8', 'thesource');
```

My goal is to create a new table `reports` with `data` from the `stats` table, but with a new key from the `links` table. It will look like this:

```
CREATE TABLE reports(
    id integer NOT NULL,
    uid integer NOT NULL,
    date date NOT NULL,
    data jsonb DEFAULT '[]'::json NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO reports(id, uid, date, data) VALUES
   (1, 1, 2020-10-01, {"uuid":{"source":"thesource"});
```

To this end, I tried to left join the table `links` in order to retrieve the `uuid` column value - without luck:

```
SELECT s.uid, s.date, s.data->jsonb_object_keys(data)->>'source' as path, s.data->jsonb_object_keys(data) as data, l.uuid
FROM stats s LEFT JOIN links l ON s.data->jsonb_object_keys(data)->>'source' = l.path
```

I tried to use the result of s.data->jsonb_object_keys(data)->>'source' in the left join, but got the error:

> ```
> ERROR:  set-returning functions are not allowed in JOIN conditions
> ```

I tried using `LATERAL` but still not valid result.
How to make this work?

Comment: Instrumental for any question like this: Postgres version, table definition (`CREATE TABLE` script), sample data, desired result.

Comment: You're right. I edited my question.

Comment: I took the liberty to fix your setup with something that works. Hope I guessed correctly ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`jsonb_object_keys()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-PROCESSING-TABLE) is a set-returning function which cannot be used the way you do - as the error messages tells you. What's more, `json_object_keys()` returns top-level *key(s)*, but it seems you are only interested in the *value*. Try [`jsonb_each()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-PROCESSING-TABLE) instead:

```
SELECT s.id
     , s.uid
     , s.date
     , jsonb_build_object(l.uuid::text, o.value) AS new_data
FROM   stats s
CROSS  JOIN LATERAL jsonb_each(s.data) o  -- defaults to column names (key, value)
LEFT   JOIN links l ON l.path = o.value->>'source';
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=92a8983282627fb45087725c880e4087)*

`jsonb_each()` returns top-level key *and* value. Proceed using only the *value*.

The nested JSON object seems to have the constant key name *'source'*. So the join condition is `l.path = o.value->>'source'`.

Finally, build the new `jsonb` value with [`jsonb_build_object()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-CREATION-TABLE).

While this works as demonstrated, a couple of questions remain:

- The above assumes there is always exactly *one* top-level key in `stats.data`. If not, you'd have to define what to do ...
- The above assumes there is always exactly one match in table `links`. If not, you'd have to define what to do ...
- **Most importantly:**
  If `data` is as regular as you make it out to be, consider a plain "uuid" column (or drop it as the value is in table `links` anyway) and a plain column "source" to replace the `jsonb` column. *Much* simpler and more efficient.

Comment: This is exactly it. Thank you ! Yes, you're right, i moved the uuid data to a new column. About the data, it wont have only 'source' in the futur but more data. But the key will stay uuid, so a column will be more effective.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that you want to join by the "source" key from the JSON column.

Instead of

```
s.data->jsonb_object_keys(data)->>'source'
```

Try this

```
s.data ->> 'source'
```

If my assumptions are correct the whole query can go like that:

```
SELECT
  s.uid,
  s.date,
  s.data ->> 'source' AS path,
  s.data -> jsonb_object_keys(data) AS data,
  l.uuid
FROM stats s
LEFT JOIN links l ON s.data ->> 'source' = l.path
```

Comment: Thank you but ... I should have post the json structure. the data column is like this : 
{"somehash' : {"source" : "the sourceidneed"}. I am using jsonb_object_keys in order to retrieve the "somehash". In this case it wont work, it returns null as path